# Flutter List<DocumentSnapshot> not getting all values

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I had a FutureBuilder (great to have loading) getting my DocumentSnapshot list from Firebase but the problem was that it was rebuilding it over and over again if I push/pop a screen. To fix that I finally placed it on `initState` but I have one problem, I'm not getting all the documents from it sometimes.

I have a button to enable country filter and disable, each time I press it almost instantly show my documents and for example I have 11 total and 5 filtered but I don't get them all sometimes and until gets the values I get app error (length of `_userList`?). I tried to place a Future to force await but I'm not being able, please advise.

`var _userList;`

```
_fetchUserList() {
    Future<QuerySnapshot> snapshot;
    if (_countryFilter) {
      //print('COUNTRY FILTER');
      snapshot = Firestore.instance.collection('u').where('country', isEqualTo: country).getDocuments();
    } else {
      //print('ALL FILTER');
      snapshot = Firestore.instance.collection('u').getDocuments();
    }
    snapshot.then((QuerySnapshot result) {
      final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
      if (documents.length > 0) {
        final List<DocumentSnapshot> availableUsers =
            documents.where((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['userId'] != _id).toList();
        //print('userList Size: ' + availableUsers.length.toString());

        List<DocumentSnapshot> userShuffle = _shuffle(availableUsers);
        setState(() {
          _userList = userShuffle;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

This is my GridView:

```
GridView.builder(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisSpacing: 10.0, crossAxisSpacing: 10.0, childAspectRatio: 0.85),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return _buildItem(context, _userList[index]);
                    },
                    itemCount: _userList.length,
                  )
```

Button:

```
onPressed: () async {
            if (_countryFilter) {
              _countryFilter = false;
            } else {
              _countryFilter = true;
            }
            await _fetchUserList();
            setState(() {});
          },
```

Comment: are you returning a promise/future from your _fetchUserList(); call?

Comment: No because if I put it on initState I can't make it work on a futurebuilder, if you can help I appreciate so much. It must be on init or will refresh everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work using some validations. Also the problem of the different user lenght was because of the "country" variable was used on the buildItem too.

```
Future _fetchUserList() async {
    setState(() {
      _userList = null;
      _userLenght = null;
    });
    QuerySnapshot snapshot;
    if (_countryFilter) {
      snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('u').where('country', isEqualTo: _myCountry).getDocuments();
    } else {
      snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('u').getDocuments();
    }

    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.documents;
    if (documents.length > 0) {
      final List<DocumentSnapshot> availableUsers =
          documents.where((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['userId'] != _id).toList();
      _userLenght = availableUsers.length;

      if (_userLenght > 0) {
        List<DocumentSnapshot> userShuffle = _shuffle(availableUsers);
        _userList = userShuffle;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

```
(_userList == null && _userLenght == null)
                      ? Container(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 50.0,
                                  height: 50.0,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                    strokeWidth: 2.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                              Text(
                                "We are loading the users",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      : (_userLenght == 0)
                          ? Container(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Center(
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.supervisor_account,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.8),
                                      size: 50.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                                  Text(
                                    "No one was found\nTry reloading the screen",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          : GridView.builder(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                                  childAspectRatio: 0.85),
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return _buildItem(context, _userList[index]);
                              },
                              itemCount: _userLenght,
                            ),
```

Hope this helps someone. With this I was able to stop screen userlist shuffle each time I push and pop a screen since it's on the initState and Button only.